# In a Function I have an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

Tags: javascript, function

I have run into the problem several times and I have read other posts but can't find what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help.

```
function switchTurn() {
    if (checkForWinner(document.turn)) {
        setMessage("Congratulations, " + document.turn + "! You win!");
  } else if (document.turn === "X"); {
       document.turn = "O";
       setMessage("It's" + document.turn + "'s turn!");
  } else {
      document.turn = "X";
      setMessage("It's" + document.turn + "'s turn!");
    }
   }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal debugger. We're trying to build a repository of good Q&As that will help people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`;` here:

```
else if (document.turn === "X"); {
```

is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
function switchTurn() {
    if (checkForWinner(document.turn)) {
        setMessage("Congratulations, " + document.turn + "! You win!");
  } else if (document.turn === "X"){
       document.turn = "O";
       setMessage("It's" + document.turn + "'s turn!");
  } else {
      document.turn = "X";
      setMessage("It's" + document.turn + "'s turn!");
    }
   }
```